# How do I have an application query Facebook users via e-mail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to try and get my user's name using their email by searching using Facebook's Graph API. The problem is, I need to do this using a user token and not using an application token. I don't want to use my user token because it doesn't make much sense to do so.

Comment: because I don't want that my application will be represented by a user account, it just doesn't make sense.